# Error installing Pylucene on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, pylucene

I'm having trouble installing Pylucene on my Windows 10 machine.

I have edited the makefile as recommended:

```
PREFIX_PYTHON=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Programs\\Python\\Python36
ANT=C:\\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\\apache-ant-1.10.1\\bin\\ant
JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)\python.exe
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc
NUM_FILES=8
```

I got the following error message when trying to build:

```
C:\pylucene-6.5.0>MinGW32-make
svn export -r HEAD http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/java/tags/lucene_3_0_2 lucene-java-3.0.2
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, svn export -r HEAD http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/java/tags/lucene_3_0_2 lucene-java-3.0.2, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:112: recipe for target 'lucene-java-3.0.2' failed
MinGW32-make: *** [lucene-java-3.0.2] Error 2
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions would be grately appreciated.

Comment: Do you have subversion (svn) installed?

Comment: @rfkortekaas, I dont think subversion is installed on my system. Should I install svn and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, the makefile is getting the subversion repositories head of license. Without subversion you will not get the source!

Comment: @rfkortekaas, you are right, after installing svn, it built and gave the following error message eventually; `/usr/bin/bash: C:apache-ant-1.10.1-binapache-ant-1.10.1binant: command not found` . I would adjust enviroment variable to include ant/bin.

Comment: Change the backslashes in the makefile in the ant line with single forward slashed!

Comment: @rfkortekaas, I have not been able to complete the installation, I still have issues with apache ant: `ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin
Path=C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin\ant"`. Here's how I set  the variable for an: `ANT_HOME=C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin
Path=C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\apache-ant-1.10.1\bin\ant"`

Comment: Use forward slashes: / as a test

Comment: @rfkortekaas, I used forward slashes as a test but got the following error message: `/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'`
`/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @user2274879 did you ever figure this out...?